# ag-grid column search not working with object as cell value

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I am using cell_renderer to define my cell, something like this:

```
        var cell_renderer = function(params) {
            var element = "";
            var values = params.value;
                angular.forEach(values, function(each_param){
                    element += '<a href="#/workunit/' + each_param.id + '" target="_blank">' + each_param.id +
                            '<span class="text-danger text-bold">'+
                            '<span class="" title="' + inactive_message +
                            '">' + inactive_flag + ' </span>' +
                            '<span class="" title="' + misconfigured_message +
                            '"> ' +misconfigured_flag + '</span>'+
                            '</span></a><br>';
                })
            return element;
        };
```

My column definnition is this:

```
                var testObject = {};
                testObject.headerName = "my header";
                testObject.field = each_branch;
                testObject.width = 200;
                testObject.cellClassRules = cell_class_rules;
                testObject.cellRenderer = cell_renderer;
                columnDefs.push(testObject);
```

Here testObject.field = each_branch , is a json object.

Hence the inbuild search functionality not working in ag-grid. Can anyone please help me here.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 8):

By default the textFormatter from Ag-grid is returning a string representation, if you include textFormatter and return the same object in the textCustomComparator you'll have the object from the valueGetter:

```
   filter: "agTextColumnFilter",
filterParams: {
    textCustomComparator: function  (filter, value, filterText) {
        //value is the object from valueGetter
    },
    textFormatter: function(r) { 
        //this is the solution
        return r; 
    }, 
    valueGetter: function getter(params) {
        return {
            ...
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The solution is to provide `valueGetter` in filter params.

Say for example you have `{ name: 'Some Name', id: 1 }`. In that case you want to filter by the name. So:

```
{
  filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
  filterParams: {
    valueGetter: params => {
      return params.data.name
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the text filter-properties on your column:

```
testObject.filter:'text',
testObject.filterParams:{
...
}
```

and then implement the **textCustomComparator** function in the filterParams object:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-text/#gsc.tab=0

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried using this, but I find the value of the cell as [object object]. How I can get the raw value here?

textCustomComparator: function(filter, value, filterText) {
                   console.log(filter);
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(value));
                  console.log(filterText);
                 }

Answer (score 0):

When using a column that is an Object, you have at least 2 options:

1. Specify a valueGetter function on the column. If you do this, the table will no longer contain the object, but rather the value returned by the valueGetter.

   valueGetter: this.getDateValueGetter("dateCol")

   private getDateValueGetter(col: string): Function {
     return function (p: ValueGetterParams) {
       if (!p.data) {
          return null;
       }
       return this.ui.convertStringToDate(p.data[col], "YYYY-MM-DD");
     }
   }
2. If you want your table to contain the object, specify both a keyCreator function and a valueFormatter function on the column.  If you do this, the column, filters, and grouping will work as expected.

   { keyCreator: (param) => {return param.value}, 
     valueFormatter: (param) => {return param.value}
   }