# Use custom filter for objects in ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an ag-grid table and I am passing some objects as data. I want to add some custom filters. Below I have a very simplified version of my problem.

I have an interface `VersionInfo` which represent the object I am passing to the grid.

```
export interface VersionInfo {
    version: number;
   // more fields here...
}
```

Then I specify the schema of the grid and add some data:

```
columnDefs = [
    {
      headerName: 'Version', 
      field: 'version', 
      filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter',
      comparator: (a, b) => b.version - a.version,
      cellRenderer: (params: ICellRendererParams) => {
        return `Custom rendering ${params.data.version.version}`;
      }
    }
];

rowData = [
    { version: {version: 3} },
    { version: {version: 5} },
    { version: {version: 8} }
];
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<ag-grid-angular 
    style="width: 500px; height: 200px;" 
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    [rowData]="rowData" 
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Everything is working fine excepet for the `comparator`. I would assume that it would sort the table in reverse order but nothing is happening instead, I just get the table as specified in `rowData` and as soon something is written into the filter field all entries are filtered. As mentioned before, this is a simplified version, but the problem is the same.

Comment: So is the filtering working correctly, and just the sort is not working? Did you want the grid to start out sorted by the Version column, in which case you want to use the `sort` option?

Comment: @MattNienow in the example both filtering and sorting is not working at all. My question is how I can add these features for complex objects. Primitive datatypes such as number and String seem to work just fine by default. If I try to add a `console.log` in the comparator function, it is never triggered.

Comment: I understand now. Using the `valueGetter` as @LuDeveloper mentions below will help you get the sort working. And then I think you need to also provide this to the filter params: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893083/ag-grid-column-search-not-working-with-object-as-cell-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everything is fine in your code but **missing** only small detail, as follows:

in your construction, set the grid `sortable` with `DefaultColDef` object like this:

```
this.defaultColDef = {
  sortable: true,
};
```

Edited:
Add this part in your column definition:

```
...
headerName: 'version',
valueGetter: (params: any) => {
  return 'Custom rendering ' + params.data.version.version;
},
...
```

Here the [solution Plnkr link](https://plnkr.co/edit/OgB1E6PRFwj06Scu) based on your code:

I hope it solves your problem. If not, please let me know.

Comment: For me the result seems to be the same as without it. I have checked the column definiton in the console and `sortable` is `true` anyway

Comment: Then can you click the Plnkr link above and paste your code in there, save it and share with me please? I am sure it is not a big deal.

Comment: The code you posted is basically it. The behaviour I want to achieve is when you filter the Version column for `3` there should be one entry in the table with `Custom rendering 3`

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/OgB1E6PRFwj06Scu check if all correct.. I replace valueRenderer with valueGetter.

Comment: it's working with valueGetter, thanks. Could you change it in your answer, I'll accept it then

Comment: I changed my answer. All the best @IanFako